# Using Data compare to copy one database over another

Tags: redgate, red-gate-data-compare

Ive used the Data Comare tool to update schema between the same DB's on different servers, but what If so many things have changed (including data), I simply want to REPLACE the target database?

In the past Ive just used TSQL, taken a backup then restored onto the target with the replace command and/or move if the data & log files are on different drives.  Id rather have an easier way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Schema Compare (also by Red Gate) to compare the schema of your source database to a blank target database (and update), then use Data Compare to compare the data in them (and update). This should leave you with the target the same as the source. However, it may well be easier to use the backup/restore method in that instance.